# deployment, install on each computer or run from network

Tags: c#, wpf, deployment

We have started our own development for some in house applications and we have come across a difference of opinion on how to deploy the applications.

My manager would like to deploy to a network location and have users all use the same executables.

Myself and my coworker would like to deploy installations and try to work something up for updating.

Is there a best practice for deployment?  Is deployment to a network location possible?  Are there cons?

Comment: So you are talking about a dumb desktop application? One developer? A Team? Considered a build server e.g. TeamCity? Permissions?

Comment: Click once deployment might work for you guys.  Particularly for pushing application updates out to everyone without having to go to each machine if you use a distributed deployment.  Here is a link to a similar question posted here before,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22291380/deployment-practices-for-net .  I would highly suggest investigating the feasibility of making the application web based, if its just not feasible then I think click once would be a good solution.

Comment: Take a look at http://serverfault.com/questions/206658/how-can-i-use-one-exe-on-multiple-machines that should answer most of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but you have to be aware that the files may be in use for a long time (e.g. people leaving their workstation up and running all the weekend). We do some kind of mixed mode: Deployment to a central repository on a fileshare, but the start of such an application in the fileshare path executes code that will either install it locally or look up the already installed application and start this, followed by the termination of the application instance started from the repository...

But you dont have to make it all yourself, you may also have a look at Click Once.

Comment: So having the actual executable files on a network location may cause issues if files are in use?  Is this an issue for the newtwork or an issue where a user might lock a file and another user's application crashes because of the lock?

Comment: Well, we have never seen any interference between the users, but it can be a damn pain in the YouKnowWhere if the binaries you want to replace are in use all the time, and you have either to find the person(s) using the binary or the administrator who is able to force these handles...